# Linq conditional group by count

Tags: linq

Consider having a `workshop` table with the following records:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Epic Car Repairs |
| 2 | Car Care Workshop - Alpha |
| 3 | Car Care Workshop - Bravo |
| 4 | Car Care Workshop - Charlie |
| 5 | Bosch Car Service Centre |

Assume all the `Car Care Workshop`'s with `id`'s `2`, `3`, `4` are part of a franchise. If I have a list of quotes submitted by all of these workshops (assume each of the 5 workshops submitted 1 quote) and assume I have a list of id's for each workshop in the franchise, how do I go about counting the quotes in linq so that all the quotes of the the franchisee workshops count as only 1?

`quotes.Count()` gives a value of `5`

`quotes.Count('somehow identify distinct franchises')` should give a value of `3`

Comment: To to this right, i.e. without inferring anything from names, there should be something like a `franchise` entity involved, or a`franchiseId` in the workshops.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to decide on a way to uniquely identify distinct values, for example name up to the first dash (-). Then you can count distinct values based on this property.

Perhaps something like this;

```
private class Workshop
{
    public Workshop(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public string UniqueName => Name.Split('-').First().Trim();
}
```

I like to use a helper extension method so that I can get distinct values by a specific property / method.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, T2>(this ICollection<T> collection, Func<T, T2> selector)
{
    return collection.GroupBy(selector).Select(x => x.First());
}
```

Your scenario;

```
[Test]
public void DistinctBy_works()
{
    ICollection<Workshop> collection = new List<Workshop>();
    collection.Add(new Workshop(1, "Epic Car Repairs"));
    collection.Add(new Workshop(2, "Car Care Workshop - Alpha"));
    collection.Add(new Workshop(3, "Car Care Workshop - Bravo"));
    collection.Add(new Workshop(4, "Car Care Workshop - Charlie"));
    collection.Add(new Workshop(5, "Bosch Car Service Centre"));

    var result = collection.DistinctBy(x => x.UniqueName).ToList();
    result.Count.Should().Be(3);
    result[0].Id.Should().Be(1);
    result[1].Id.Should().Be(2);
    result[2].Id.Should().Be(5);
}
```